# How to get specific fields of a list of nodes in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have the following code in Drupal to get the list of nodes that match certain conditions:

```
function get_failgames($form, &$form_state) {  
        $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'game_results')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
                ->fieldCondition('field_division', 'tid', (array) $form_state['values']['division'])
                ->fieldCondition('field_ft_home_team_goals', 'value', 5, '=')
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

  $result = $query->execute();

        dpm($result);
}
```

Now I want to get one or more fields of those nodes. How should I do this? Load each single node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `node_load_multiple()` function & pass `array_keys($result['node'])` as an argument to the same. Please check sample code below:

```
function get_failgames($form, &$form_state) {  
        $query = new EntityFieldQuery();

        $query
        ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'game_results')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
        ->fieldCondition('field_division', 'tid', (array) $form_state['values']['division'])
        ->fieldCondition('field_ft_home_team_goals', 'value', 5, '=')
        ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.

        $result = $query->execute();
        $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
        dpm($result);
        dpm($nodes);
}
```